# Append custom field value in WooCommerce product name on cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

I'm trying to change the name of the product in cart and checkout pages.

I have the following code to add some cart meta data:

```
function render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item = null ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    /* Woo 2.4.2 updates */
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }

    if( isset( $cart_item['sample_name'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => $cart_item['sample_name'], "value" => $cart_item['sample_value'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
```

But I also want to change the name of the product.

For example if the product name is **`Apple`** and custom field **`'sample_value'`** value is **`with sugar`**, I would like to get **`Apples (with sugar)`**.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` action hook:

```
// Changing the cart item name
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'customizing_cart_items_name', 20, 1 );
function customizing_cart_items_name( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through each cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Continue if we get the custom 'sample_name' for the current cart item
        if( empty( $cart_item['sample_name'] ) ){
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            // Get the product name (Added compatibility with Woocommerce 3+)
            $product_name = method_exists( $product, 'get_name' ) ? $product->get_name() : $product->post->post_title;
            // The new string composite name
            $product_name .= ' (' . $cart_item['sample_name'] . ')';

            // Set the new composite name (WooCommerce versions 2.5.x to 3+)
            if( method_exists( $product, 'set_name' ) ) 
                $product->set_name( $product_name );
            else
                $product->post->post_title = $product_name;
        }
    }
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: this didn't work for me, but when I removed the `empty()` function it works.