# Run JS function in add_action WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I have this action in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_custom_price', 10, 1);
function adding_custom_price( $cart ) {
global $current_user, $woocommerce, $wpdb;

    // This is necessary for WC 3.0+
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Avoiding hook repetition (when using price calculations for example)
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

            $quantity = 0;
                foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                    $quantity += $cart_item['quantity'];
                    $product_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();
                    $product_price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();
                    $categorie_id = $cart_item['data']->get_category_ids();
                    $korting_product = get_field( 'discount_points', $product_id );

                    //Zet prijs min benegas korting
                    $cart_item['data']->set_price($product_price - $korting_product);
                }

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$quantity');</script>";

}
```

But the with this line:

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$quantity');</script>";`

The cart keeps loading after changing the quantity so what am I doing wrong. I do not get an alert.

Comment: You can't use a js script in a woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hooked function as this hook is ajax powered and run multiple times… it's not made to include any JS code and will disturb Ajax making an infinite loading loop…

Comment: Ok, is there any way then to replace the `span` value with `$quantity` value?

Comment: Try to re-write your question adding more details regarding what are you trying to do, and why…

Comment: Think I can manage my problem in an order way. I found this topic where you answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415887/append-custom-field-value-in-woocommerce-product-name-on-cart-and-checkout 
Now it changes the productname but what I want is to add a span beneath the productname instead of changing the productname.

Comment: This kind of hooks doesn't allow to change the html structure…